# Fabric parallel task not bound to a specific set

Tags: python, parallel-processing, fabric

I'm looking for a way to define a task with multirun, which will run on a set of servers defined in the commandline (via roles or hosts).

All examples I've seen so far, try to do something like:

```
env('app-nodes').multirun('some command')
```

But I don't want to hardcode the role. I'd like to define it with `fab -R ...` instead. What are my options here?

I'd expect this to work:

```
@task
def some_task():
    env().multirun('some command')
```

but that throws `TypeError: '_AttributeDict' object is not callable`

Comment: Does it have to be a Python function, or would GNU Parallel qualify? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Comment: I wanted to integrate it into existing set of fabric scripts, so preferably no parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You'll prolly want to use task args and feed it into tav's env() that way:
http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.1.1/usage/fab.html#per-task-arguments

Also why would you expect an empty set for hosts to work?

Comment: As per: http://tav.espians.com/fabric-python-with-cleaner-api-and-parallel-deployment-support.html (#Contextualised Tasks) context could be just the default one... unfortunately it isn't (it's set from the @task parameters)

Comment: yeah from his docs it's either set as a param from @task or in the env.ctx tuples. So you could edit the ctx value with that and use env() or just do something like: def t(use_hosts): env(use_hosts).run(..)